# How to set vector background on a Bottom Sheet Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Is there a way to set the background of `BottomSheetDialogFragment` as a Vector? Simply setting the `android:background="@drawable/vector"` did not work.

**vector.xml**

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:viewportWidth="1123"
    android:viewportHeight="1785"
    android:width="1123dp"
    android:height="1785dp">
    <group
        android:translateY="-651">
        <path
            android:pathData="M48.0035499 652.223154L1089.36686 820.119125C1108.75028 823.244256 1123 839.975434 1123 859.609162L1123 2436L1123 2436L-3 2436L-3 695.662195C-3 671.361666 16.699471 651.662195 41 651.662195C43.3457374 651.662195 45.6877185 651.849779 48.0035499 652.223154Z"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering, you have added `android:background="@drawable/vector"` to the rootview of the layout. Check if any of the **child views are occupying the parent dimensions and has set the background to white**. In that case your rootview won't be able to show your the exact shape.

Please provide your layout file as reference, in case this is not the issue.